# Variable values get lost when switching between objects in a class included in a class

Tags: c++, class, variables, object

**The Problem is that variables loose their values**.
The variables `selectable_values_array` and `searched_array_size` contain the correct values while inside the initialisation of the `find_number::find_number`.
But when the `find_closest` object is called the variables are containing
values like -28 and 4214247.
As a logical consequence the samplerate_return returns just garbage.

So what am i missing here ?
Is there a method of safely passing a variable/values inside a class ?

**Edit:** Added the reduced MyClass and main.

```
#include "MyClass.h"

int main()
{
    int32_t samplerate_return = 0;
    int32_t samplerate_request = 7;

    MyClass ADC_1 ();

    while(1) {
      samplerate_return = ADC_1.select(samplerate_request);
    }
}
```

The first Class:

```
#ifndef MyClass_H
#define MyClass_H

    #include "find_number.h"

    class MyClass
    {
    public:
        MyClass();
        int32_t select(int32_t the_searched_number);
        int32_t the_selected_number;

    private:
        int32_t Integer_array[];
        int32_t Numbers_in_Integer_array;
        bool init();
        find_number MyNumber;
    };
```

And the `MyClass.cpp`

```
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    init();
    find_number MyNumber;
}

bool MyClass::init()
{
    int32_t Integer_array[] = {2,5,10};
    Numbers_in_Integer_array =  (sizeof(Integer_array)/sizeof(*Integer_array));
    find_number MyNumber (Integer_array,Numbers_in_Integer_array);
    return 0;
}

int32_t MyClass::select(int32_t the_searched_number)
{
    the_selected_number = MyNumber.find_closest(the_searched_number);
    return the_selected_number;
}
```

This is the header file of the "Find_Numbers" class:

```
#ifndef find_number_h
#define find_number_h

class find_number
{
public:
    //Constructor:
    find_number(int32_t  *selectable_values,int32_t cells_in_array);
    find_number(); // = default;
    //Class Objects:
    int32_t find_closest(int32_t target_value);

private:
    int32_t searched_array_size;
    int32_t *selectable_values_array;
 };
    #endif
```

And the corresponding `find_numbers.cpp`

```
    #include "find_number.h"

        find_number::find_number(int32_t *selectable_values, int32_t cells_in_array)
        {
            selectable_values_array = selectable_values;
            searched_array_size = cells_in_array;
        }

        find_number::find_number() {};

       int32_t find_number::find_closest(int32_t target_value)
        {
            int32_t difference = abs( target_value - *selectable_values_array);
            int32_t closest_integer = selectable_values_array[0];
            // calculating stuff
            return closest_integer;
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (eg there is no `main` but just a class definition that by itself isnt doing anything), input, expected and actual output... btw if you add that you may shorten the text a bit. Code is better explained by code rather than words

Comment: Show us the code where you construct the `find_number` object, as the problem is likely with how you're calling it and not in the code you've shown.

Comment: I just added the requested other code parts in reduced form.

Comment: `find_number MyNumber (Integer_array,Numbers_in_Integer_array);` in `MyClass::init()` (and `find_number MyNumber;` in the constructor) creates a *local* variable, it does not assign to the class member of the same name